# Controlling resolution of full domain pcolormesh cells

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm not sure whether this is a Cartopy or Matplotlib question, so I apologize if this would have been better suited for Matplotlib.

I am transitioning from NCL (NCAR Command Language https://www.ncl.ucar.edu/) to Python. Previously, I was using NCL to contour with a method of "CellFill" (https://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Document/Graphics/Resources/cn.shtml#cnFillMode). In Python, I am using pcolormesh to render a gridded dataset with a horizontal grid spacing of 3-km. In NCL, regardless of whether I am plotting the full domain or an area zoom, the resolution of the resulting image appears to be consistent using a PNG output. In Python however, if I use pcolormesh with an area zoom it looks identical to my NCL plot but if I try and plot the full domain, it looks different.

I've traced this down to the figure resolution. At the full domain view in Python, however I have my figure settings configured causes the 3-km cells in certain areas to become "blurred together" making it *appear* as if the entire region is a certain contour value when in actuality there are areas with no values in between.

Here is a CONUS example of pcolormesh:
[image]

And here is a full CONUS version from NCL:
[image]

There are several areas of note, but one obvious area is the NM/AZ region. If I zoom in very closely in both Python and NCL in this region, the resulting images look identical. But at the CONUS view it looks like there's much more shading in this area than there actually should be in the Python version.

```
crs = ccrs.PlateCarree() # Lat/Lon
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(15, 15))
ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE.with_scale('50m'), linewidth=BORDERWIDTH,edgecolor=BORDERCOLOR)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.STATES, linewidth=BORDERWIDTH,edgecolor=BORDERCOLOR)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, linewidth=BORDERWIDTH,edgecolor=BORDERCOLOR)
ax1 = plt.subplot(111,projection=crs)
norm = BoundaryNorm(LEVELS,ncolors=plt.get_cmap('plasma').N,clip=False)
cf1 = ax1.pcolormesh(diffsum.lon0,diffsum.lat0,diffsum,cmap='plasma',transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),norm=norm)
plt.savefig('testing%s.png' % (DSTRING))
```

Note that if I manually increase the DPI used in the resulting image to something rediculous like 1000, or increase the figure size to 100x100 inches, it also looks OK but the resulting image is so gigantic it makes it cumbersome to view on the screen.

Is there something I am missing about pcolormesh that I should be doing to help better adapt the resolution of the cells being shaded with respect to the resolution of the actual figure itself?